# Can't load component,, automatically redirect me to login page

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using Angular 7 to create an admin dashboard. I created a home page which supposed to be working before Login. But the problem is that it doesn't work, it work only after Login, but before login I can see it loaded for 1 second on the screen, and then an automatic redirection to Login page.

You can see below my app.module code.

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path     : '',
        component: HomeComponent,

    },
    {
        path        : 'apps',
        loadChildren: './main/apps/apps.module#AppsModule',

    },
    {
        path        : 'pages',
        loadChildren: './main/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',

    },
    {
        path        : 'ui',
        loadChildren: './main/ui/ui.module#UIModule'
    },
    {
        path      : '**',
        redirectTo: 'apps/dashboards/analytics'
    },

];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,

    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeDbService, {
            delay             : 0,
            passThruUnknownUrl: true
        }),

        // Material moment date module
        MatMomentDateModule,

        // Material
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,

        // Fuse modules
        FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
        FuseProgressBarModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseThemeOptionsModule,

        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        AppStoreModule,

        //spinner
        NgxSpinnerModule,

        HomeModule
    ],
    providers   : [
        DatePipe,
        MehdiService,
        TokenService,
        AuthService,
        AfterLoginService, 
        ProfileService,
        BeforeLoginService,
        AcademyCourseService,
        AcademyCoursesService,
        {  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
            multi: true
         }
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

And here is the code of home.module :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports     : [

    ],
})
export class HomeModule
{
}
```

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: no, there are no console errors

Comment: you have any http interceptor?

Comment: yes, I use a TokenInterceptorService

Comment: Would  be helpful if you add home.component.ts code.

Comment: Even when  home.component.ts is empty, I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your's `TokenInterceptorService`.

Check your's `HomeComponent` html selector if it's inside any component only visible when logged in.

Comment: I don't think so, when I delete it, I got the same problem

Comment: Is your HomeComponent selector inside any Component that is only visible when logged in?

Comment: absolutely not !